# Need Example HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I try again to **scrape** for an exemple.

Actually i have the follow code :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic


Public Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        'Enable SSL Suppport'
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        'WebPage to Scraping'
        Dim link As String = "https://www.nextinpact.com"
        'download page from the link into an HtmlDocument'
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load(link)
        'select the title'

        Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//section[@class='small_article_section']")

        If Not div Is Nothing Then
            For Each node As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class='color_title']//a[@class='ui-link'][contains(text())]")
                Console.Write(div.InnerText.Trim())
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Actualy i try to catch all the title from

> "//section[@class='small_article_section']"

But how i do to get all the title ?
For the first title the xpath is

> "//h2[@class='color_title']//a[@class='ui-link'][contains(text(),'Les
> obligations de Netflix passeront d')]"

Thanks you.

Edit:
I try an other example,

with

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles?manufacturer=sideshow+collectibles&type=premium+format%28tm%29+figure&brand=aspen")
Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c-ProductList row']")
```

Now i try to get for each product the title, with :

```
For Each node As HtmlNode In div.SelectNodes("//h2[contains(text(),'Grace')]") 'That is for Only Grace 
        Console.Write(node.InnerText.Trim())
    Next
```

But with

```
//h2[contains(text(),'Grace')]
```

i have Nothing and i want Gace and Aspen and try with

```
.//h2[contains(text()]
```

and nothing too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it.

```
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlWeb().Load("https://www.nextinpact.com/")
    Dim div As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//section[@class='small_article_section']")

    'If div IsNot Nothing Then 'I think this part is pointless as it will always exist
    For Each node As HtmlNode In div.SelectNodes(".//h2[@class='color_title']/a") 'a class='ui-link' doesn't exist so do h2/a
        Console.Write(node.InnerText.Trim())
    Next
```